# Performing logical operation inside Higher Order Component on prop set

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a higher order component, to perform some logic and pass the result down as a prop to a functional component, to show the data.

In my main component, I pass down the prop percentage down to my HOC

```
 <Match
                inputName={this.state.inputName}
                inputSname={this.state.inputSname}
                percentage={this.state.percentage}
                result={this.state.result}
                show={this.state.showResult}
                />
```

inside my HOC

I perform a switch statement and pass down the result as a prop to my functional component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

const MatchWrapper = WrappedComponent => {
return class MatchWrapper extends Component {
state = {
  type: ""
};

componentDidMount(){

}

createTypeHandler = () =>{
  console.log(this.props.percentage);

  console.log(this.props.show)

  let type = "";
  switch (true) {
    case this.props.percentage > 75:
      type = "succes";
      break;
    case this.props.percentage > 50 && 75 >= this.props.percentage:
      type = "mediocore";
      break;
    case this.props.percentage <= 50:
      type = "failure123";
      break;
  }
  this.setState({
    type: type
  });
}

render() {
    console.log(this.props.show)
    console.log(this.state.type)
    {this.props.show &&
        this.createTypeHandler
    }
  return (

    <div>
      <WrappedComponent type={this.state.type} {...this.props} />
    </div>
  );
};
}
};
export default MatchWrapper;
```

now I have an issue on where to render my createTypeHandler, I can't put it inside componentDidMount, because that is rendered, right when the component is mounted, and ideally we want to wait for the user to pass in some data. So I thought the best alternative would be to make a handler, to be executed, the prop show is equaled to true.

But does neither seems to work? How can I render the function or set the state of ´type´ when I now the user has given the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the resulting `type` is based on the passed props, you do not need to keep it in the state. Just calculate it inside the `render` method.

And for this kind of component (*where you do not need `state` nor any of the life-cycle methods*) you can use a pure component

```js
import React from "react";

const MatchWrapper = WrappedComponent => (props) => {
  const {show, percentage } = props;
  let type = "";
  switch (true) {
    case percentage > 75:
      type = "succes";
      break;
    case percentage > 50 && 75 >= percentage:
      type = "mediocore";
      break;
    case percentage <= 50:
      type = "failure123";
      break;
  }

  return show && <WrappedComponent {...props, type} />
}

export default MatchWrapper;
```

---

Just a heads up, the main problem with your original code was that you were not calling the `createTypeHandler`. You need to add `()` to call a method. So `this.createTypeHandler()`. But then calling a method that changes the state from inside the `render` method is a big no-no. For such case you need to use the `componentDidUpdate` life-cycle method. But for this case it is simpler to not use state at all.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i figured it was not a good idea, to call a function inside the render method.  I tried using the componentDidupdate hook, my issue, was that it kep rendering to often, and would essentially lead to performance problems later on, but this solution works perfectly!